# What's the difference between Twitter Bootstrap and Plusstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for some time. I heard a session that mentioned that [Plusstrap](http://xbreaker.github.com/plusstrap/index.html) is preferable. When looking at Plusstrap it looks like an identical clone. Also, I couldn't find any clues to why it was forked in the first place. 
I would like to hear if someone can shed some light about this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more than a clone of twitter bootstrap at this stage (v 0.1.0)

https://github.com/xbreaker/plusstrap/commits/master

Only cosmetic changes and bootstrap replaced by plustrap.